# Is there a way to add a column called "Rank" in pandas that would take a list of values as number 1 being the highest value, and so on and so on?

Tags: pandas

```
df['Total'] = df['HP'] + df['Attack'] + df['Defense'] + df['Sp. Atk'] + df['Sp. Def'] + 
df['Speed']
df['Total'] = df.iloc[:,4:10].sum(axis=1)
df['Total'] = df['Total'].astype(int)
cols = list(df.columns.values)
df = df[cols[1:3] + [cols[-1]] + cols[3:12]]
df = df.sort_values(by=['Name','Total'], ascending=[True,False])
```

My output looks like this:

```
                      Name   Type 1  Total  ... Speed  Generation  Legendary
510                Abomasnow    Grass    494  ...    60           4      False
511  AbomasnowMega Abomasnow    Grass    594  ...    30           4      False
68                      Abra  Psychic    310  ...    90           1      False
392                    Absol     Dark    465  ...    75           3      False
393          AbsolMega Absol     Dark    565  ...   115           3      False
```

Is there to ad a new column titled 'Rank' in the index that will rank the Names by their total from first to last?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```py
import numpy as np

df["Rank"] = np.argsort(df["Total"])
```

[numpy's argsort function](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) "returns the indices that would sort an array"

Answer (score 0):

Using pandas, you can add columns easily.

```
s= pd.Series(df.sort_values(by='Total').index)
df['Rank']= s
```

And you may find a column "Rank" In your dataframe.